# Where do I add modules to initramfs? (15.04)

Tags: boot, drivers, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I need to add these modules because my usb keyboard is not working when I try to type my encrypted password.

```
usbcore
uhci_hcd
ehci_hcd
usbhid
```

I guess I need to add these to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules, but where exactly do i add them. Here is the modules file:

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
```

Where am I supposed to add it here, and am I doing the right thing (is it safe)?

Comment: Do not post duplicates.

Comment: Please do not reask questions. If you want to add information, please use the [edit] button.

Answer (score 5):

Just add them at the end of the file like that

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
usbcore
uhci_hcd
ehci_hcd
usbhid
```

But I don't think it is related to your problem.